# NTLM on Nginx as load balancer

Tags: iis, nginx

I have IIS6 services with NTLM auth.
For my testing purposes i need to configure load balancer for these services.
I've confiured simple upstreams for a few services and now i have a problem with NTLM authentication.
How to configure Nginx to support NTLM in reverese proxy mode?

Answer (score -1):

The goal is to enable keepalive and set HTTP version to 1.1:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass http://myupstream;
    }
}


upstream myupstream {
    server localhost:12345;

    keepalive 32;
}
```

Comment: Do NOT do this, clearing the `Connection` header leads to security issues ([nginx.org](https://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2016-February/049889.html)). Instead use the stream api, e.g. [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/754351/what-is-a-correct-ways-to-allow-login-to-an-iis-site-through-a-reverse-proxy)